# Django Admin Reverse Relations

Tags: django, django-admin

If you are on the django admin page for the model Group. You don't know that there is a reverse relation to user.

Some people (not me) have difficulties with it.

Is there a way to show all reverse relations, so that you can jump to the matching admin pages?

Example:

On admin page for Group I want a link to User (and all other models which refer to it).

This should happen by code, not by hand with templates.

Answer (score 2):

This method doesn't automatically add links to all related models of a Group, but does for all Users related to a Group (so for one related model at a time). With this you'll get an inline view in your Group with the related Users.

You could probably extend this technique to make it automatically work for all related fields.

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = User
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ('change',)

    def change(self, instance):

        if instance.id:

            # Django's admin URLs are automatically constructed
            # based on your Django app and model's name.
            change_url = urlresolvers.reverse(
                'admin:djangoapp_usermodel_change', args=(instance.id,)
            )

            return '<a class="changelink" href="{}">Change</a>'.format(change_url)

        else:
            return 'Save the group first before editing the user.'

    change.allow_tags = True


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    inlines = (UserInline,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in this extension I created for Django admin pages to link to related objects:

https://github.com/gitaarik/django-admin-relation-links

It's quite easy to use and makes the admin a lot more convenient to use :).